# Problems with Backbone.Model callback and THIS

Tags: backbone.js

I'm building a simple weather widget. The current weather conditions are read out of the National Weather Service xml file and then I want to parse and store the relevant data in the model but the callback for the $.ajax won't connect (the way I'm doing it).

```
var Weather = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            _.bindAll( this, 'update', 'startLoop', 'stopLoop' );
            this.startLoop();
        },
        startLoop: function(){
            this.update();
            this.interval = window.setInterval( _.bind( this.update, this ), 1000 * 60 * 60 );
        },
        stopLoop: function(){
            this.interval = window.clearInterval( this.interval );
        },
        store: function( data ){
            this.set({
                icon : $( data ).find( 'icon_url_name' ).text()
            });
        },
        update: function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET', 
                url: 'xml/KROC.xml', 
                datatype: 'xml' 
            })
            .done( function( data ) {
                var that = this;
                that.store( $( data ).find( 'current_observation' )[ 0 ] );
            });
        }
    });
    var weather = new Weather();
```

The data is read correctly but I can't get the done function of the call back to call the store function. (I would be happy if the "done" would just parse and then do "this.set".

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4):

I think you just need to move your `var that = this;` up one level:

```
update: function(){
    var that = this; // <-------------- You want this 'this'
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET', 
        url: 'xml/KROC.xml', 
        datatype: 'xml' 
    })
    .done( function( data ) { // <----- rather than the 'this' in here
        that.store( $( data ).find( 'current_observation' )[ 0 ] );
    });
}
```

You want to capture the current value of `this` in your `update` method, by the time your `done` is called, it will be too late as the `done` callback will already have the wrong `this`.

Comment: That was the problem. Thank you.

Comment: The naming convention I find most useful is `var _this = this;` in outer scope.

Comment: @Alex: That's the one I use now as well, I prefer the `self` name but `window.self` makes that problematic.

Answer (score 1):

The answer above will work, but there's a built-in facility for this with underscore. Try this:

```
.done(_.bind(function( data ) { // <----- rather than the 'this' in here
    this.store( $( data ).find( 'current_observation' )[ 0 ] );
}, this));
```

This way, you'll never have to do a `that=this` as you set the execution context to `this` with [`_.bind`](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#bind).

Also, I've found that `_.bindAll(this, ...)` doesn't guarantee that you'll bind to `this`. Using `_.bind` at the level I need it always works.